# Add UIView and UILabel to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using GitHub project https://github.com/mayuur/MJParallaxCollectionView

I am trying to add a UIView and UILabel to the cells being displayed. I have tried so many solutions it would probably just be easier to ask someone how to do it.

So with that can someone add a UIView and UILabel to the UICollectionView displaying some text? This can be done programmatically or via storyboard, whichever suits your style.

I tried adding related logic in MJCollectionViewCell.m setupImageView method. Also, tried MJRootViewController cellForItemAtIndexPath method. But I still can't get the UIView and UILabel to display over the UIImage object in MJCollectionViewCell.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIImage *image;
```

MJCollectionViewCell.h

```
//
//  MJCollectionViewCell.h
//  RCCPeakableImageSample
//
//  Created by Mayur on 4/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 RCCBox. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define IMAGE_HEIGHT 200
#define IMAGE_OFFSET_SPEED 25

@interface MJCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

/*

 image used in the cell which will be having the parallax effect

 */
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIImage *image;

/*
 Image will always animate according to the imageOffset provided. Higher the value means higher offset for the image
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGPoint imageOffset;

//@property (nonatomic,readwrite) UILabel *textLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImage;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSString *text;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) CGFloat x,y,width,height;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger lineSpacing;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView* overlayView;



@end
```

MJCollectionViewCell.m

```
 //  MJCollectionViewCell.m
    //  RCCPeakableImageSample
    //
    //  Created by Mayur on 4/1/14.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 RCCBox. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "MJCollectionViewCell.h"

    @interface MJCollectionViewCell()

    @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIImageView *MJImageView;

    @end

    @implementation MJCollectionViewCell

    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) [self setupImageView];
        return self;
    }

    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self) [self setupImageView];
        return self;
    }

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    #pragma mark - Setup Method
    - (void)setupImageView
    {
        // Clip subviews
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;

        /*
        // Add image subview
        self.MJImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
        self.MJImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.MJImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        self.MJImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
        [self addSubview:self.MJImageView];
        */

        //New Code in method
        // Add image subview
        self.MJImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
        self.MJImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.MJImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        self.MJImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;

        //self.overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.4f];
       // UIView *anotherView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)];

       //  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 20.0)];
       // label.text = @"Hello";

       // [anotherView addSubview:label];

        [self addSubview:self.MJImageView];
        [self addSubview:self.overlayView];
        [self addSubview:self.textLabel];
    }

    # pragma mark - Setters

    - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
    {
        // Store image
        self.MJImageView.image = image;

        // Update padding
        [self setImageOffset:self.imageOffset];
    }

    - (void)setImageOffset:(CGPoint)imageOffset
    {
        // Store padding value
        _imageOffset = imageOffset;

        // Grow image view
        CGRect frame = self.MJImageView.bounds;
        CGRect offsetFrame = CGRectOffset(frame, _imageOffset.x, _imageOffset.y);
        self.MJImageView.frame = offsetFrame;
    }

    //This was added from MPSkewed may need to remove if not called.
    - (void)setText:(NSString *)text{
        _text=text;

        if (!self.textLabel) {

            CGFloat realH=self.height*2/3-self.lineSpacing;
            CGFloat latoA=realH/3;

           // self.textLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,latoA/2, self.width-20, realH)];
            self.textLabel.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(.5, .5);
            self.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-ultralight" size:38];
            self.textLabel.numberOfLines=3;
            self.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            self.textLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            self.textLabel.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(1, 1);

            self.textLabel.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(asin(latoA/(sqrt(self.width*self.width+latoA*latoA)))));
            [self addSubview:self.textLabel];
        }

        self.textLabel.text=text;
    }
    @end
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used in the MJCollectionViewCell.m file?

Comment: Posted the code for you @Mike.

Comment: Put a breakpoint where you call [self addSubview:] those three times, and do 'po self.overlayView' and 'po self.textLabel' in the debugger. What do you get?

Comment: Have you tried to connect the label and the view to the corresponding views in the storyboard?. It is easier than make it programmatically. After that you just have to set properties and make the class feet your needs.

Comment: @Mike (lldb) po self.overlayView is returning nil. Not sure how to resolve that.

Comment: @ThXou I have tried using connections also.

Comment: You have to create it. It looks like the code that creates it is commented out above it.

Comment: Is the overlayView and textLabel the subviews you created, or is the MJImageView what you added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .h of the cell:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UILabel *label
```

In the .m of the cell:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) UILabel *label
```

In the `setupImageView` method (which you should probably rename to be more generic), **after** the image view is created, something like this:

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame]; // or CGRectZero if you are using auto layout

self.label.textColor = ...; // any other setup you want to do

[self addSubview:self.label];

self.label.frame = ...; // or set it up using auto layout
```

And in your data source’s `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.label.text = @"some text";
```

That is a simple approach. In practice, I would probably expose a property for the string only, not the whole label, but that depends on what you are doing and how much control you need.